# How to repeat existing word with placeholder to each row in Notepad ++?

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-group, regex-greedy

current lines are

```
cp filename1*.csv 
cp filename2*.csv 
cp filename3*.csv 
....
cp filenamen*.csv
```

I'd like to replace these rows with extra words, eventually all lines should be like this

```
cp filename1*.csv filename1.csv 
cp filename2*.csv filename2.csv 
cp filename3*.csv filename3.csv 
....
cp filenamen*.csv filenamen.csv
```

So it is like to replace

```
{cp\s}{filename\d+}{.csv}
```

with

```
{0}{1}{2}{1}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to transform your stuff in Notepad++ from

```
cp filename1*.csv 
cp filename2*.csv 
cp filename3*.csv
```

to

```
cp filename1*.csv filename1.csv 
cp filename2*.csv filename2.csv 
cp filename3*.csv filename3.csv
```

With a finding regex of `cp(\s+)(\w+)(\d+)\*\.csv` and replace regex of `cp\1\2\3*.csv \2\3.csv`.

I am not sure if the star was supposed to be in the same since it was not clear from your post whether it means something else or not, so I just assumed it was a literal character and escaped it with `\*`. If it's supposed to be something else like more numbers, you can trivially fix up the answer with your knowledge since you appear to be familiar with regex already. Also if the `*` is supposed to be multiple digits, then the `\d+` will handle that.

I also captured the spaces because you did that in your example, and I followed it by capturing and outputting to try to keep it as close to what you wanted as possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use capturing groups the syntax would be `()` instead of `{}`

You could use 2 capturing groups and in the replacement use `$0` to refer to the whole match and add group 1 and group 2 to get the captured values for filename and csv.

Instead of using `\s` which also matches a newline you could match 1+ times a horizontal whitespace character `\h+`

Find

```
\bcp\h+(filename\d+)\*(\.csv)
```

Replace with:

```
$0 $1$2
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B0gpiM/1)